# Detecting key combinations

Tags: wpf, keyboard-input

I want to detect when a combination like Ctrl-C is pressed in a WPF application. What I've read online says to use something like the following in the KeyDown (or KeyUp) Event:

```
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) && (e.Key == Key.S))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Save!");
}
```

I'm just trying to understand how this works. As I understand it, e.Key contains the key that was pressed that triggered the event and Keyboard.Modifiers contains the information about the state of the Control key **right now**. Is it safe to assume that the Control key will still be down by the time the KeyDown event gets handled?

For example, I restart Firefox and it grinds away loading a bunch of tabs, and in the meantime I hit Ctrl-S in my application. There is a delay in getting to KeyDown, and the application thinks just S has been pressed.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`KeyBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx) instead, they define full gestures without such a separation.